# How can i get form->field() value?

Tags: forms, field, yii2

In short, I have the following code:

```
<?= $form->field( $isntmodel, 'id')->textInput() ?>
<?= Html::a('<i class="mdi-action-done"></i>', ['add-item', 'id' => ???], [
    'class' => 'btn-btn-add pull-right',
]) ?>
```

This code is wrong.

So. I need get value which will input by user. And set it instead `???`

`$form->field()` must have `$model, $attribute, $options = []`. How can I write field not using $model and $attribute? It is not table column, I need just get value and set it instead `???`

I try that

```
  public function actionAddItem($id) {
    $model = $this->$model;
    $product = Product::findOne($id);
    $orderItem = new OrderItem();
    $orderItem->order_id = $model->id;
    $orderItem->title = $product->title;
    $orderItem->price = $product->getPrice();
    $orderItem->product_id = $product->id;
    $orderItem->save();
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
  }
```

But it throws an exception. At row with `$model = $this->$model` , and I don't know how from field submit id to link

Adding item is work if i put this in browser `http://yii2-shop/backend/web/order/add-item?modelid=13&id=1&quantity=4`

**UPD**

Now my form looks like

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([]); ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $n ?></td>
        <td><?= $form->field( $model, 'newOrderItemId')->textInput()->label(false) ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?= $form->field( $model, 'newOrderItemQuantity')->textInput()->label(false) ?></td>
        <td>
            <?= Html::a('<i class="mdi-action-done"></i>', [
                '/order/add-item',
                'modelid' => $model->id,
                'id' => $model->newOrderItemId,
                'quantity' => $model->newOrderItemQuantity,
            ], [
              'class' => 'btn btn-add pull-right',
              'data-toggle'=>'tooltip' ,
              'data-placement'=>'bottom',
              'title'=>'Добавить товар',
            ]) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And `add-item` looks like

```
public function actionAddItem($modelid, $id, $quantity) {
    $model = $this->findModel($modelid);
    $product = Product::findOne($id);
    $orderItem = new OrderItem();
    $orderItem->order_id = $model->id;
    $orderItem->title = $product->title;
    $orderItem->price = $product->getPrice();
    $orderItem->product_id = $product->id;
    $orderItem->quantity = $quantity;
    $orderItem->save();
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

`newOrderItemId` and `newOrderItemQuantity` are just public variables which I mark at `Order` model. I can't get form field value for submit it to `add-item`

Comment: ID is from user input? Seems weird.

Comment: @arogachev please, look at update of question

Comment: Note that you can create model for form, without table. Did you try this?

Comment: @arogachev nope.. I can't understand how it will works. And can't understand right way for creating model for form. And how it will work inside `order/update`. But i gonna try it now.

Comment: @arogachev I tried something, after looking at https://github.com/samdark/yii2-shop/blob/master/backend/models/MultipleUploadForm.php and https://github.com/samdark/yii2-shop/blob/master/backend/controllers/ImageController.php - is didn't work. What should I do? Write conditions at `actionIndex()` or at `actionAddItem`? I created `AddOrderItem` model and wrote variables inside. Added `'action' => '../add-item'` to `ActiveForm::` and changed `a` on `submitButton` - its give me same result: "missing modelid, id, quantity" Are you can help me with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. I solved the problem.

I created `AddOrderItem` model for announce variables

```
<?php namespace backend\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class AddOrderItem extends Model {

  public $modelid;
  public $id;
  public $quantity;

  public function rules() {
    return [
      [['modelid','id','quantity'], 'integer'],
    ];
  }

}
```

And I edited `actionUpdate()` now it's looks like

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $addOrderModel = new AddOrderItem();
    if ($addOrderModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
      $product = Product::findOne($addOrderModel->id);
      $orderItem = new OrderItem();
      $orderItem->order_id = $model->id;
      $orderItem->title = $product->title;
      $orderItem->price = $product->getPrice();
      $orderItem->product_id = $product->id;
      $orderItem->quantity = $addOrderModel->quantity;
      $orderItem->save();
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
      return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'addOrderModel' => $addOrderModel
      ]);
    }
  }
```

At `views/order/update` i added following row

```
<?= $this->render('_addItemForm', ['model' => $addOrderModel]); ?>
```

And `_addItemForm` now contains this:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

  <td><?= $form->field( $model , 'id')->textInput()->label(false) ?></td>

  <td></td>
  <td></td>

  <td class="text-center"><?= $form->field( $model , 'quantity')->textInput()->label(false) ?></td>

  <td>
    <?= Html::submitButton('<i class="mdi-action-done"></i>',[
      'class' => 'btn btn-add pull-right',
      'data-toggle'=>'tooltip' ,
      'data-placement'=>'bottom',
      'title'=>'Добавить товар',
    ]) ?>
  </td>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I can't believe what I done it by myself. And I'm glad that I had no one to help, because now I know more.